# Spotlight indexing problem with external SSD in macOS Sonoma 14.2

Tags: finder, external-disk, spotlight, sonoma, indexing

I have a problem with my Sandisk Extreme external hard drive in exFat format; When using Spotlight it does not find the files, and if it does, there are few results when there are many more on my Macbook (for example, music). It also happens to me when I use the colored labels, if I want to see my files with labels directly from the sidebar, none of them load or display, as if I had never labeled them, but if I enter the folder I can see the labeled files without a problem.

The funny thing is that this problem does not happen to me with a Lacie brand external HDD in APFS format, on that disk I have absolutely no indexing problems.

I've already tried the Add/Remove solution in Spotlight, I've already tried the terminal commands, and I've even tried deleting the `.Spotlight-V100` folder from my Sandisk hard drive to get the index rebuilt and I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: D oyu need it formatted in exFat?

Comment: Please edit to include the Terminal commands you have tried, and any output / errors from them.

Comment: @benwiggy has a point. Does Spotlight even support exFAT?

Comment: @benwiggy Yes, I am a DJ and I work with a specific software (Rekordbox), this software requires that the SSDs be in exFat format, and the HDDs in any format. The problem is that in Ventura I did not have the indexing problem, in that version of Macos everything was fine, the problem only occurs in Sonoma. This is the second time I am in Sonoma, I tried 14.1 and had the same problem, so I downgraded to Ventura, and now that 14.2 is out I tried again and the "fault" has not been corrected.

Comment: @benwiggy I have another HDD disk in Exfat format and it has no problem with Spotlight or labels.
It is impossible for it to be a failure of my SSD, since it works without problems for me in Ventura, and also in Catalina (I have another Mac with Catalina); If it were a problem with my SSD, it would not work well in Ventura or the Catalina version either.

Comment: @AndyGriffiths sudo mdutil -s / (enabled), also try adding and removing from Settings/privacy-spotlight.

Is there any other additional way from Terminal?

Comment: If you have another ExFat drive that does work in Spotlight, then we need to figure out what the difference is between the two devices/volumes.

Comment: @benwiggy I spent all day looking for information helping me with BingAI and found many other cases with the same problem from exFat and Sonoma. I think the problem is definitely that, the format in Sonoma. In Ventura I haven't had any problems, only in Sonoma. I will have to wait for an update, I don't know how to report it directly to Apple (which would be good to do).

Comment: You can report problems to Apple here: https://www.apple.com/feedback/

Comment: Friends, thank you very much. I had to downgrade to Ventura, because there I don't have any problems with my SSD disk in exfat. As I said above, searching the forums I was surprised by the number of people who also cannot work in Sonoma with SSDs in ExFat format. I'll have to wait for a solution... for the moment Ventura is the best! Thank you very much for your help, I am new to this page but I love all the information about Apple that is here, I will take your instructions into account when using this website.